# Javascript onclose event

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

How can I run javascript when user close the browser. I tried to use 'onunload', but it calls every time I press F5/refresh button?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the Javascript on the page is concerned, there's no difference between closing the browser, navigating to another page or refreshing the same page.

Comment: nickf is right though - attaching an event to onbeforeunload or onunload will trigger on closing, refreshing or navigating away.

Comment: My guess is that even though your answer is correct, it disappointed the OP greatly.