# Call a javascript function on tab /browser close not on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, pageload

I have an issue . I am trying to clear a cookie value on tab close. and i have created a function But it clears value on page reload also . I also tried this solution [stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767136/how-can-i-detect-browser-tab-refresh-or-close-using-javascript)

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires+"; path=/";
}
function unloadPage()
{ 
    var check=getCookie('mycookie')
    if(check)
    setCookie('mycookie','','-2'); 
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
});
```

Function is working but problem is **it is also clearing cookie on page reload** . but i only want to clear cookie if user close the window.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494206/javascript-onclose-event

Comment: i have checked this . but o want to know if there is  any method.

Comment: check if this add any help to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129319/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close-event-in-angular-only-close-not-refresh

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple solutions like "`unload`", "`onbeforeunload`", "`performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]`" but nothing worked for me.

I was trying it on the multipage web application. What worked is mentioned below:
I needed to call logout function on the close tab/browser not reload.
On the page where you want to logout set a local storage variable.

```
localStorage.setItem('isReloaded', true);
```

Now, on your home page

```
componentDidMount(){
if(localStorage.getItem('isReloaded') != null){
  this.logout(); //logout function
}
```

and, inside logout function reset the local storage value

```
logout(){
 //your logout code
 localStorage.removeItem('isReloaded')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have done this on react application and its work for me
on index.html file write this in script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
    window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "true";
  });
  window.onunload = function (e) {
    const newTabCount = localStorage.getItem("tabsOpen");
    if (newTabCount !== null) {
      localStorage.setItem("tabsOpen", newTabCount - 1);
    }
  };
</script>
```

Then go on main file and write this code

```
useEffect(() => {
  // define increment counter part
  const tabsOpen = localStorage.getItem("tabsOpen");
  if (tabsOpen == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("tabsOpen", 1);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("tabsOpen", parseInt(tabsOpen) + parseInt(1));
  }

  // define decrement counter part
  window.onunload = function (e) {
    const newTabCount = localStorage.getItem("tabsOpen");
    if (newTabCount !== null) {
      localStorage.setItem("tabsOpen", newTabCount - 1);
    }
  };
  if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
    window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "false";
  } else {
    const newTabCount2 = localStorage.getItem("tabsOpen");
    let value = localStorage.getItem("isMySessionActive");
    if (value == "true") {
      if (newTabCount2 - 1 == 0) {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "false";
      } else {
        window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "false";
      }
    }
  }
}, []);
```